# Contar a altura e a largura de uma "imagem" (char* usando \n) - C++

Tags: c++

Boa noite! Em um dos parâmetros do meu construtor, eu estou passando o seguinte **char ***

```
+---+\n|A  |\n| H |\n|  A|\n+---+
```

Em seguida, o construtor chama o SetText(), passando esse char*, e dentro do SetText(), eu teria que contar a altura e a largura desta "imagem", a qual seria 5x5. Presumo que seja usando o **\n**.

Andei procurando várias funções ou algoritmos para dar split no \n, mas nem um com sucesso.

No PHP, há o **split()** que reparte a string no char desejado e separa todo o resto em arrays (o qual já daria pra contar a altura e largura), há algo parecido/igual no C++ ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugeria o uso de `std::string` ao invés de `char *`, sempre que possível.

Podes criar a tua própria função genérica para separar uma `std::string` de dado um delimitador.

Fica aqui um exemplo usando apenas funções da biblioteca std.

```
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

vector<string> *splitHelper(const string &str, char delimiter, vector<string> &elements) {
    stringstream ss(str);
    string item;
    while (getline, item, delimiter)) {
      elements.push_back(item);
    }
}

vector<string> splitString(const string &str, char delimiter) {
    vector<string> elements;
    splitHelper(str, delimiter, elements);
    return elements;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char *test = "+---+\n|A  |\n| H |\n|  A|\n+---+";  //este passo é desnecessário. Uma vez que estás a usar C++ deverias usar, sempre que possível, `std::string` ao invés de usar `char *`

    string str(test);
    const vector<string> words = splitString(str, '\n');

    //imprimir as palavras
    copy(words.begin(), words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n");
}
```

O vector `words` irá conter cada um dos elementos. Podes determiner o tamanho da imagem contando o número de caracteres de cada uma dos elementos. A altura da imagem será o número total de elementos do vector `words`.